# Looking for C++ implementation of OpenGL gears example

Tags: c++, opengl

I have often seen the spinning gears OpenGL example ( I think originally done by SGI) but I today I have only been able to find C and Ruby implementations, can anyone point me to a c++ implementation?

Comment: I think that if you compile the C version with a C++ compiler it will work.  Why do you want a C++ version?

Comment: Removed "gears" tag, which usually refers to Google Gears, and may be misleading in this context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What, in particular, would you be looking for in a C++ implementation that the C one doesn't provide? OpenGL is a C API, and thus a C demonstration is practical. A C++ implementation would call all the same functions in the same order and to the same effect, it would likely just wrap the implementation in an object. This doesn't really further one's understanding of the core API, and can possibly add a layer of obfuscation to those not familiar with some C++ styles and patterns.

If what you are really looking for is an example of initiating OpenGL wrapped in a C++ framework, I made a few of those a while back. You can find them [here](http://www.tojiart.com/OpenGL/). Please note that I'm no longer actively maintaining the code or page, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mess around with OpenGL i strongly reccomend using [OpenSceneGraph (OSG)](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) since you can focus better on computer graphics aspects instead. It's using all the C++ magic and design patterns.